# Azure Media Player does not work with AES protection on iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, azure, encryption, azure-media-services

We are having issues playing a protected with AES (with JWT token authentication) video on iPhone 6 (A1586). The following error arrears:

> 0x50300000 - The video playback was aborted due a corruption problem
>   or because the video used features your browser did not support

The very same video plays w/o any problems when encryption is disabled.

The thing is that the *sample* that replicates such scenario published by Azure Media Player team *does not work either* and fails with the very same error! It's available here: https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/. This sample named as follows:

> AES (JWT token) – On Demand [Tears of Steel Teaser]

How can I do protected video streaming via Azure media Services/Player on iPhone? Is it supported scenario at all?

Here is the relevant code that sets up the delivery policy:

```
    deliveryPolicy = context.AssetDeliveryPolicies.Create(
        DeliveryPolicyName,
        AssetDeliveryPolicyType.DynamicEnvelopeEncryption,
        AssetDeliveryProtocol.SmoothStreaming | AssetDeliveryProtocol.Dash | AssetDeliveryProtocol.HLS,
        new Dictionary<AssetDeliveryPolicyConfigurationKey, string>
        {
            { AssetDeliveryPolicyConfigurationKey.EnvelopeKeyAcquisitionUrl, contentKey.GetKeyDeliveryUrl(ContentKeyDeliveryType.BaselineHttp).ToString() }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this exact scenario in the list of Azure Media Player "known issues": https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/Known_Issues.html.

> AES and restricted token content does not playback using iOS and older
>   Android devices. In order to achieve this scenario, a proxy must be
>   added to your service.

This workaround that is proposed by Azure team is described in this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-make-token-authorized-aes-encrypted-hls-stream-working-in-safari/. I did not personally test it yet.

[image: workaround]

**UPDATE.** The workaround works after minor changes -- there was an issue with URL encoding for second-level HLS playlist. Here is full WebAPI 2 controller code that makes the trick for me: http://pastebin.com/kq7Zfw88.

Comment: Hey, I'm working with the same thing and experiencing the same issues you mentioned... Using your code isn't solving it for me but one thing I can say is that my playback manifest url ends in manifest(encryption=cbc)... I used to add the apple format with a comma, like manifest(encryption=cbc,format=m3u8-aapl), but it's still failing...

Comment: @MaximilianoAmbrosini, that's very interesting. Unfortunately, I'm not able to check it right now, but it was definitely a working approach for us. I would suggest to at least try to arrange the setup w/o encryption, just to eliminate another variable.

Comment: Hey Eugene, it finally worked for me! even using encryption or not... it's basically the code you shared on pastebin, and on the client sending manifest(encryption=cbc,format=m3u8-aapl) for encrypted content. Looks like one thing that was preventing it to work was the iphone simulator, which has some problem with the audio.

Comment: @MaximilianoAmbrosini, glad to hear! Good job!

Comment: I implemented your workaround. Too bad this is still needed in 2020. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt sure, no problem, glad it worked for you too!