# AES encrypted video stream not working with azure media player in ios devices

Tags: c#, ios, azure, encryption, azure-media-services

We are facing blocker while playing aes encrypted content in ios devices.
We have already referred below links -

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-make-token-authorized-aes-encrypted-hls-stream-working-in-safari/

[Azure Media Player does not work with AES protection on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506415/azure-media-player-does-not-work-with-aes-protection-on-iphone)

https://github.com/AzureMediaServicesSamples/HLSSafariProxy

Issue is that i am unable to call the proxy server (as explained in above links) from azure media player. Below is the code to call proxy server from player -

```
        <video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoplay="" controls="" width="640" height="400" data-setup="{"techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS","html5FairPlayHLS","silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}">
<source src="XXXX-XXXXX" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" data-setup="{"protectionInfo": [{"type": "AES", "authenticationToken": "Bearer XXXXX"}],"streamingFormats":["SMOOTH","DASH","HLS"]}"/>

<source src="http://localhost:5002/api/AzureMediaServicesManifestProxy/TopLevel?playbackUrl=XXXX-XXXX/manifest&amp;token=Bearer XXXXX-XXXXX" (proxy server api) 
type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" data-setup="{"disableUrlRewriter": true}"/>
</video>
```

I am getting error "No compatible source was found for this media"
Please help in this regard.

Comment: Hey did you manage to sort it out? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Not able to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the source multiple times which is confusing the iOS player. can you try setting the source just with the proxy URL?

Comment: I tried setting single source also but it didn't work.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  IoS is quite happy with multiple sources as proven herehttps://mingfeiy.azurewebsites.net/